# Enable NTLM SSO in Firefox via Group Policy

Tags: firefox, ntlm, single-sign-on

I would like to enable NTLM for a specific intranet site. For that I need to configure the following parameter:

`network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` to add `x.xyz.com`

How can I achieve this via group policy for Firefox Users?

I've come across this script (below) but unsure if this is the best solution

https://www.felixrr.pro/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/FirefoxSSO.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the [Enterprise deployment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment) article.

First write the following to `\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\prefs\autoconfig.js`:

```
pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg.js");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

Then put your actual settings in `\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\mozilla.cfg.js`:

```
// the first line must be a comment
pref("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", "domain.test");
pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "domain.test");
```

In the second file you can use `defaultPref(key, value)`, `clearPref(key)`, `pref(key, value)`, or `lockPref(key, value)`; the last three will override user settings.

---

It's possible to make Firefox download the configuration over HTTPS, but this doesn't give many advantages over plain Group Policy; it can be useful though where AD is not available:

```
lockPref("autoadmin.global_config_url", "https://example.com/firefox/lockdown.js");
```

The 3rd-level .js file works the same way as the 2nd-level one.

Comment: To be picky, the path should be `\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\autoconfig.js`. Specifically `prefs` should be `pref`

Comment: Quoting "Integrated Authentication" in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication , "site-list is a comma-separated list of URL prefixes or domains of the form: site-list = "mydomain.com, https://myotherdomain.com".  Wildcards did not work for me but domains without schemas did.